# duplicate view upon data change?

Tags: android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

My CardView duplicate elements upon data change, the vardView is within a tab, and the way i declared that tab fragment as following;

in the onCreateView, i declared all the necessary firebase links and value events listeners to retrieve the required data related to the elements displayed on the cards.

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            if(snapshot !=null){
                for (DataSnapshot child: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Log.i("MyTag", child.getValue().toString());
                    imagesfeedsList.add(child.child("address").getValue(String.class));
                    authorfeedsList.add(child.child("author").getValue(String.class));
                    ratingfeedsList.add(child.child("rating").getValue(String.class));
                    locationfeedsList.add(child.child("location").getValue(String.class));
                    publicIDfeedsList.add(child.child("public_id").getValue(String.class));

                }
                Log.i("MyTag_imagesDirFinal", imagesfeedsList.toString());

                mImages = imagesfeedsList.toArray(new String[imagesfeedsList.size()]);
                author = authorfeedsList.toArray(new String[authorfeedsList.size()]);
                ratingV = ratingfeedsList.toArray(new String[ratingfeedsList.size()]);
                locationV = locationfeedsList.toArray(new String[locationfeedsList.size()]);
                publicID = publicIDfeedsList.toArray(new String[publicIDfeedsList.size()]);

                numbOfAdrs = Long.valueOf(imagesfeedsList.size());
                LENGTH = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(numbOfAdrs));
            }
```

right after the snippet the adapter setup;

```
    ContentAdapter adapter = new ContentAdapter(recyclerView.getContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    return recyclerView;
}
```

Then comes the view holder with a RecycleView, declaring the cardView elements. One of the elements is a ratingBar, and here where the ratingbar Listener is to submit the user rating on a specific picture.

after that the content adapter;

```
 public static class ContentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {
    // Set numbers of List in RecyclerView.

    private Context mContext;

    public ContentAdapter(Context context) {

        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.authorName.setText(author[position]);

        holder.ratingValue.setText(ratingV[position]);

        holder.locationValue.setText(locationV[position]);

        Picasso.with(mContext).load(mImages[position]).into(holder.picture);
  @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return LENGTH;
    }
}
```

My problem is whenever the user submits a rating or even when the data related to any of the elements on anycard changes, the view gets duplicated ( i mean by the view, the cards ), a repetition of the cards, with the new data chnages displayed ?

i a not sure what is in my above code structure causing this and how to fix this repetitions, i mean i need the cards to be updated with the new data but not duplicated?

Answer (score 1):

All right, so the problem was that every time the data changes, in the onCreate the imagesFeedList, ratingFeedList, etc does not get rid of the old information stored in it from the initial build, so when the refresh happens triggered by onDataChange, the new information gets added to the previous information, which cause the view to repeat the cards, thus just at the beginning of onDataChange and before storing any information in the several feedLists, it must be cleared;

```
   imagesfeedsList.clear();
   authorfeedsList.clear();
   ratingfeedsList.clear();
   locationfeedsList.clear();
   publicIDfeedsList.clear();
```

and by that i made sure the view does not repeat build up based on old information.